# How to align elements properly using CSS

Tags: css

My site layout is very simple. I want it to look something like this:

- One row of text that spans the width of the page.
- Four separate columns of text below that.
- Two columns below that where:

  - The column on the left is thinner and spans the remaining height of the page.
  - The column on the right has one short row of text and then another row of text below it that spans the remaining height of the page.

[image]

Each red block is text. Right now I just have each block underneath the next one, all centered. I want it to be laid out like the image above.

I cannot seem to figure out how to do this properly. Using relative alignment is a mess. Percentages don't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The websites are divided in to multiple blocks (or columns). It's up to the designer/developer to divide this to independent groups (like sidebar, headers, footers, content etc.)

Learning the fundamentals is quite important. [this site](http://learnlayout.com//) has pretty decent intuitive tutorial HTML

Also checkout

- [Designing a HTML5 layout from scratch](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/04/designing-a-html-5-layout-from-scratch/)
- [Semantic HTML5 layout](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146409/Semantic-HTML5-Page-Layout)

Also take cues from the websites you bump into with the help of developer tools packed with browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by breaking it up into big blocks:

[image: A true work of art]

From there, just make the structure:

```
<header>
    ...
</header>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<aside>
    ...
</aside>

<div id="main">
    <article>
        ...
    </article>

    <article>
        ...
    </article>
</div>
```

The CSS is pretty simple. Just look up **fluid two column layout css** and read through one of the many articles out there.